# How can I hide step calls in the Jenkins log

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

While polling a status in my Jenkins pipeline, the used commands (`httpRequest`, `readJSON`, `sleep`) produce a lot of log entries.

```
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] httpRequest
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] httpRequest
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] sleep
After 10 tries artifact is still being processed
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
```

Is it somehow possible to hide these outputs / prevent them from being printed?

Answer (score 0):

Using Simple Theme Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin) may resolve your problem. This plugin allows to customize Jenkin's appearance with custom CSS and JavaScript. 
You can ovveride display mode to none in pipeline-annotated CSS class.

```
.pipeline-annotated {
    display: none;
}
```

And you will not see any lines prefixed with [Pipeline] after that.

But, unfortunately there is a bug in the newest version of Simple Theme Plugin.

You can find a discussion of this problem here:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41845